# Django JS Translation

Tags: javascript, django, localization

I've been trying to solve this for 2 hours now, but I could't find anything.

JS file:

```
 13     var element = document.createElement("input");
 14     element.setAttribute("type", "button");
 15     var sh_ag = gettext("Show Agreement");
 16     element.setAttribute("value", sh_ag);
 17     element.setAttribute("name", "show_agreementtt");
 18     element.setAttribute("id", "id_show_agreement");
 19     element.setAttribute("class", "show_agreement");
```

Localization Command:

> $ django-admin.py makemessages -l tr
>
> $ django-admin.py compilemessages

.po file:

```
#: media/js/agreement_admin.js:18 media/js/agreement_admin_setproc.js:15 
msgid "Show Agreement" 
msgstr "Sözleşmeyi Göster"
```

But it doesn't show the translated string for "Show Agreement". Every other thing in .po file, works well, except this exact string (and there are 2 more strings like this). How can I solve this problem?

Comment: did you restart the django process? also are you compressing js files server side, because there's no way for a client side js file to magically callback the server upon rendering

Comment: By django process, you mean web server? Yeah I restarted it ;)

Comment: No I didn't. Actually, all other js translations work but this ones.

Comment: Isn't the `-d` option required to makemessages from js? e.g: `./manage.py makemessages -d djangojs -l es`